# Dockerfile parent for ARM architecture

Tags: docker, arm64, buildx

I want to build Docker image for AMD and ARM Graviton2 processors. I already know about multi-arch CLI command `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64`, manifests and the fact that Docker will pull the right image variant matching architecture.

I wonder if I have to use in my Dockerfile for ARM as a parent [`arm64v8/ubuntu:20.04`](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/ubuntu/) or it's fine to use [`ubuntu:20.04`](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu) for both? Will it work the same way on both architectures? What's the purpose of this official [arm64v8](https://hub.docker.com/u/arm64v8) dockerhub repo?

There is a significant difference in build times - 5min with `FROM ubuntu:20.04` vs 30min with `FROM arm64v8/ubuntu:20.04`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out that this [`ubuntu:20.04`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/ubuntu/library/ubuntu/20.04/images/sha256-c0dd38485ed8b6e149d2fc935d1c61a3b750cda3b3eace0ad6df4abe33fa2b90?context=explore) and this [`arm64v8/ubuntu:20.04`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/arm64v8/ubuntu/20.04/images/sha256-c0dd38485ed8b6e149d2fc935d1c61a3b750cda3b3eace0ad6df4abe33fa2b90?context=explore) two images has exactly the same SHA. So Ubuntu:20.04 is only the parent of all these per-arch images and if you run `docker manifest inspect ubuntu` you will see it all.

So it's clear that `arm64v8/ubuntu:20.04` repo is only for the case you want to build ARM image on different architecture (if you don't want to use multibuild `buildx` command). It that case you have to start writing your Dockerfile with `FROM arm64v8/ubuntu:20.04`.